# select * duplicates, then select * non-duplicates - mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

The question is for the example table structure:

mytable

```
fielda, fieldb
val1    valx
val2    valy
val3    valz
val1    vala
```

I want to select from mytable with a query:

```
fielda, fieldb
val1    valx
val1    vala
```

basically select * from table where fielda is duplicated.

then with a different query select from mytable

```
fielda, fieldb
val2    valy
val3    valz
```

val1 on fielda was encountered as a duplicate therefore it wasn't selected and the rest were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query sorts the table which duplicated `fieldA` are on top of the list.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT fieldA, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY fieldA
        ) b ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA
ORDER BY b.totalCount DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5225a/1)

This query selects duplicate records only.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT fieldA, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY fieldA
        ) b ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA
WHERE b.totalCount > 1
ORDER BY b.totalCount DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5225a/2)

and this one, selects records which are not on the second query (*above*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT fieldA, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY fieldA
        ) b ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA
WHERE b.totalCount = 1
ORDER BY b.totalCount DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5225a/3)

Comment: Do you see performance issues using these queries on the following occassion: (SELECT a.* FROM tableName a INNER JOIN(SELECT fielda, COUNT(*) totalCount from tableName group by fielda) b ON a.fielda=b.fielda WHERE b.totalCount=1 AND flag1='value' AND flag2<='value' AND flag2>'value' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(flag2) LIKE '%value%' AND flag3!='value' ORDER BY fieldc DESC LIMIT 5) - What I mean is wouldn't this select absolutely all first from tableName not allowing to set clauses for then doing the join? Can this be optimized? Thank you

Comment: @lbennet your query seems not wotking because `flag2` can't be less than and greater than at the same timw. just rewrite it into `b.totalCount = 1 AND 
  flag1='value' AND 
  (flag2<='value' OR 
  flag2>'value') AND 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(flag2) LIKE '%value%' AND 
  flag3!='value' `

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, thanks for pointing that out, what I meant was - as I don't have the experience to tell how mysql works with strong precision - if setting the WHERE after the join was performed is first making a select of all records in the database to then apply the where, I don't know if I'm explaining well the question, I am concerned about a performance issue by selecting first all records in the database to then apply the clauses as it looks as that is happening from the syntax.

Comment: all other conditions are ok except this `FROM_UNIXTIME(flag2) LIKE '%value%'` as it will not be using index.

Answer (score 2):

```
select fielda, fieldb from mytable group by fielda having count(*) >1

select fielda, fieldb from mytable group by fielda having count(*) =1
```

Comment: did you test this? don't you know *grouping* makes it single record for each `fielda`

Comment: @JohnWoo yes indeed grouping makes it single records but thats why he uses the count to show you total number of repeated records under each. An adjusted query would look like.

SELECT fielda, fieldb, COUNT(fielda) FROM mytable GROUP BY fielda HAVING COUNT(*)  > 1

SELECT fielda, fieldb COUNT(fielda) FROM mytable GROUP BY fielda HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Answer (score 0):

For the first:

> SELECT * FROM tbl GROUP BY fielda HAVING COUNT(*)>1

For the second:

> SELECT DISTINCT(fielda) FROM tbl